# How to use logger to log an error into stackdriver?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, syslog, fluentd, stackdriver

I have a VM micro instance running on google compute cloud and I want to log an error message to stackdriver. This page https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation shows this example

`logger "Some test message"`

which works great for normal messages, but I want stackdriver to recognize some messages as errors, so that they would show up here https://console.cloud.google.com/errors, which would allow me to get email notifications.

I'm aware that the `gcloud` tool has a beta logging solution, but I'm hoping to avoid installing the extra components it requires.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read over the docs about formatting at https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/formatting-error-messages

Something like:

```
  {
   "message": "Some test message",
   "context": {
     "reportLocation": {
       "functionName": "my_function"
    }
   },
   "serviceContext": {
     "service": "my service",
   }
  }
```

You'll need the message to be the `jsonPayload` of the log entry, not the `textPayload`. I believe the agent will automatically recognize JSON messages, but if there are also non-JSON messages it may fall back to using text in all cases. In that case, using a dedicated log for the errors should help.

You may also be interested in the docs on how messages are grouped together: https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/grouping

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried your example with `logger "$json"` (in shell) and it shows up in stackdriver but not error reporter. I also tried the same thing but replacing new lines with `\n` like so `json='{\n   "message": "Some test message",\n   "context": {\n     "reportLocation": {\n       "functionName": "my_function"\n    }\n   },\n   "serviceContext": {\n     "service": "my service",\n   }\n  }'`

Comment: When you expand the log entry in the cloud console logs viewer, what payload type is the content in (json, text, proto)?

Comment: I think it's just text, but here's the response https://gist.github.com/bijoutrouvaille/881d3b8780ba2e35e3e4dc3320172189

Comment: `textPayload` is the trick.  It looks like the agent doesn't fully parse the syslog entry.  If the message were e.g. in a file, I suspect it would work better. Are you planning to use `logger` to generate the messages long term?

Comment: I'd like to avoid, if possible, installing additional components, especially ones that require manual configuration.

Comment: also systemd automatically pipes logs to syslog, I think.

Comment: Here's a question about getting fluentd to convert text into json payloads that might help (but I think needs some more details): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933111/stackdriver-json-payload-in-logs-from-normal-text-payload-using-google-fluentd-a